# What is the likelihood that the Apocalypse of John is not inspired?

Tags: revelation, canonicity, pseudepigrapha

**Could we just be keeping the Apocalypse of John out of the Traditions of Men?**

What are the best arguments for and against this book being Inspired?

- Some early Christians claimed it was written by the Apostle John's gnostic arch-nemesis, Cerinthus.
- Many didn't consider it canon until less than 1000 years ago.
- In this book Jesus says "I come quickly", but in the Gospels he says he doesn't know when he's coming.
- RH Charles, Martin Luther, and other Christians of old held doubts regarding if this book was from God.
- It says to "keep the sayings" of this book, but there are no sayings to keep.
- In efforts to prolong and promote their circulation, Pseudepigrapha was known to warn the reader not to add to or delete from their fake books, and pseudepigrapha would pronounce curses to scare people who doubted the book, or pronounce blessings to lure more people into covetously reading them (no other book of the Bible does this).
- Many potential Biblical contradictions involve this book, which at times appears to also contradict itself.
- It's famous for causing confusion and fear.  God is not the author of confusion and has not given the Spirit of fear.
- A major reason for the schisms in Christianity has often been this book.  No single book has devided Christianity like this book.
- If the book of Jude were the last book in the Bible, it has a very beautiful conclusion for closing out the Bible's Canon.

Comment: I suggest you begin your quest with Herman Hoskier's extensive study of the subject _Manuscripts of the Apocalypse_. I can find only _opinion_ in the proposals above.

Comment: This question is off topic; see [canonical history of *Revelation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation#Canonical_history), [authorship of *Revelation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorship_of_the_Johannine_works#Book_of_Revelation), [development of the *New Testament* canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_the_New_Testament_canon), [antilegomena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilegomena), [Luther's canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luther's_canon), [Swedenborg's *New Testament* canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Church_(Swedenborgian)#New_Testament) etc.

Comment: You will need to make a more quoted (with verse) series of accusation to make these ideas stick.  Eg, "Keep the sayings" in Rev 22:9 is actually, "keep the words of this book".  I could go through your whole list like this.  The Gospel of John has probably provided mere debate than Revelation.

Answer (score 1):

It’s simple. John doesn’t mention a single ‘thing’ that hasn’t a firm foundation in the Old Testament. Everything can be referenced back. And, when you do, it matches, without contradicting.

So if you accept that the Old Testament authors were inspired, then at the very least John was *via* them. Notwithstanding that John adds clarity.

The book of Revelation is a difficult book to understand unless *you* have the correct foundation. And that’s been lacking, and ‘standing’ on the wrong foundation *leads* to erroneous conclusions such as your list.

It’s only recently that many important pieces to the puzzle have surfaced. Recently equals the last 40 to 50 years. Example recent archaeological finds that have the exact symbols that are described in Revelation.

One of several - An ancient stone, dated at least 2000bc found with this *exact* image…

**REVELATION 17:3** *Then the angel carried me away in the Spirit into a wilderness. There I saw a woman sitting on a scarlet beast that was covered with blasphemous names and had seven heads and ten horns.* **4** *The woman was dressed in purple and scarlet, and was glittering with gold, precious stones and pearls. She held a golden cup in her hand, filled with abominable things and the filth of her adulteries.* **5** *The name written on her forehead was a mystery:*

(Cylinder seal, Mesopotamia. Akkad period)

No, Revelation is inspired. And the evidence is mounting.

Comment: Upvoted for a thoughtful answer.

Comment: Is there a source for "An ancient stone, dated at least 2000bc found with this exact image"?

Comment: @RayButterworth … https://www.academia.edu/47513815/Satan_the_Great_Dragon_Enlil_Ushumgallu_and_Bashmu_Chpts_1_4_Corrupting_the_Image_2_Hybrids_Hades_and_the_Mt_Hermon_Connection_by_Dr_Douglas_Hamp.

Comment: @Dave, that reference is nearly a hundred pages long. It contains 47 "Mesopotamia"s, 27 "Akkad"s, and 37 "stone"s. It does not contain keywords such as "wilderness" or "forehead". Could you be more specific?  Or better yet, quote the text and include the image in the answer. It's not reasonable to expect everyone that reads this answer to individually go through the work of researching this claim.